# Edit hosts - run as administrator does not work

Tags: windows-7, administrator, hosts-file

I am trying to edit hosts file on my computer.

I click start -> find notepad shortcut -> run it as administrator (window on dimmed background appears) -> i press yes -> find hosts file -> edit it -> press file-save

But, it still opens the dialog where i want to save the "new" file. If i press save, a new .txt file is created.

Any suggestions?

(I am the only user AND administrator on my computer)

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you select the existing hosts file in the "Save" dialogue? Notepad should ask you if you want to overwrite the file, so click Yes to that prompt. Does that work?

Comment: maybe the file is read only?

Comment: @leonigmig i did, like the Indrek said and the dialog window said that the file is READ ONLY, yes. What should i do now?

Comment: before you save, right click on the file and go to properties, then un-check read only.

Comment: i made it an answer so you can give me some points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you save, right click on the file and go to properties, then un-check read only.

Comment: i can't uncheck it

Answer (score 2):

The way you do it, it should work. Probably you have installed a security tool (antivirus or something else) that prevents the file from being modified. You can check also the permissions manually (properties security dialog.) Maybe the permissions were changed through such a tool.